# NullPointerException when enumerating array after instancing all of its members?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, parallel-processing, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a piece of code involving threads and I've setup the following for loop to instantiate them all:

```
for (Buyer buyer : buyers) {
    isPrime = (rand.nextInt(10) + 1 < 3);
    buyer = new Buyer(warehouse,
                      isPrime,
                      "buyer" + ++i);
    buyer.start();
    System.out.println("started buyer: " + i);
}
```

After that I'm instantiating some other threads then I join these buyer threads again to wait for the program to finish:

```
System.out.println("Joining buyers. ");
for (Buyer buyer : buyers) {
    buyer.join();
    System.out.println("Joining thread: " + buyer.getName());
}
```

When I run my program I get 1 NullPointerException on the following line: `buyer.join();` All threads finish execution but non of them seem to want to join at that point. What is going on here?

here is the code for the buyers thread:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Buyer extends Thread{
    private int packsBought = 0;
    private boolean isPrime;
    private Random rand;
    private Warehouse warehouse;

    public Buyer(Warehouse warehouse, Boolean isPrime, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.isPrime = isPrime;
        this.rand = new Random();
        this.warehouse = warehouse;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(this.packsBought < 10) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.rand.nextInt(49) + 1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                
            }
            Order order = new Order(this.rand.nextInt(3)+ 1, 
                                    this, 
                                    this.isPrime);
            this.warehouse.placeOrder(order);
        }
        System.out.println("Thread: " + super.getName() + " has finished.");
    }

    public int getPacksBought() {
        return this.packsBought;
    }

    public void setPacksBought(int packsBought) {
        this.packsBought = packsBought;
    }

    public boolean isPrime() {
        return isPrime;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in:

```
for (Buyer buyer : buyers) {
    isPrime = (rand.nextInt(10) + 1 < 3);
    buyer = new Buyer(warehouse,          // <--- this is wrong 
                      isPrime,
                      "buyer" + ++i);
    buyer.start();
    System.out.println("started buyer: " + i);
}
```

you are not really initializing the elements from list `buyers`. This:

```
buyer = new Buyer(warehouse,
                          isPrime,
                          "buyer" + ++i);
```

will not change the reference saved on the list `buyers`. Yes, you will create and start a bunch of threads. But in:

```
System.out.println("Joining buyers. ");
for (Buyer buyer : buyers) {
    buyer.join();
    System.out.println("Joining thread: " + buyer.getName());
}
```

you are not calling join on the threads (*i.e.,* buyers) that you have created, and started. And for you to get a NPE in

```
buyer.join();
```

is because you have initialized the list of Buyers with `null`, thinking that you could initialized then on the loop:

```
   for (Buyer buyer : buyers) {
        isPrime = (rand.nextInt(10) + 1 < 3);
        buyer = new Buyer(warehouse,
                          isPrime,
                          "buyer" + ++i);
        buyer.start();
        System.out.println("started buyer: " + i);
    }
```